# How to minimize the distance between the point $(-1,0)$ and the curve $y^2 - x^3 = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization

Given the equation of  a curve : $y^2 - x^3 = 0$, it is demanded to find the shortest distance from the point $(-1,0)$ to this curve.

Here is what I tried:

1. solve the curve formula for $y$:
   **y²=x³**
2. write the function of the distance between$(-1,0)$ and the curve:
   **d(x,y)=√((1+x)²+y²)**
3. replaced in d $y^2$ with $x^3$ and squared $d(x,y)$:
   **x³+x²+2x+1=h(x)**
4. attempted to find the minimum of $h(x)$:
   **h'(x)=3x²+2x+2**
   but this derivate never equals to zero, so couldn't find any minimum for the function $h(x)$ because it tends -∞ when $x$ tends to -∞

Then i tried with Lagrange multipliers and found:

- $2y(1+λ)=0  \implies  λ=-1$ or $y=0$
  I rejected $y=0$ because for y=0 gradient of $y^2-x^3$ isn't linearly independent which is one of the conditions to use Langrange method.
- $3x^2+2x+2=0$ (same as $h'(x)$ so it doesn't have a solution)
  So I'm stuck with is and don't know how to solve the question, any help ?

Comment: Do you mean from the point $(1,0)$?  Otherwise, the answer is a very simple $1\ \text{unit}$ and is evident by inspection and concavity.

Comment: The curve has a cusp at the origin, so it has no derivative there; this is going to give either method, which is dependent upon differentiation, a difficulty.  On the other hand.  If you look at a graph of the curve and the point you are given, it will be clear what the closest point on the curve to $ \ (-1 \ , \ 0 ) \ $ is.  [On the other hand, if the point is supposed to be $ \ (1 \ , \ 0 ) \ $ (as Andrew Chin suggests), then you need to find the points on the curve where the normal line to the curve passes through $ \ (1 \ , \ 0 ) \ \ . \ ]$

Comment: A minimum for a function can be at a critical point, or at an edge of the function's domain. Hint: The domain for $x$ is not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So whenever the function isn't differential at a point and the constraint is satisfied (at this point) it could be the extrema and I shouldn't eliminate it completely? Ty aschepler I didn't find the minimum of h(x) because I forgot to set the condition on x>=0

Comment: @Jazmine is the point $(-1,0)$ or $(1,0)$?

Comment: It is actually (-1,0). But now I'm also wondering how to do it for (1,0)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged "multivariable calculus", you have presumably dealt with parametric curves.  We can get around the problem created by the cusp in this "semicubical parabola" by parametrizing it using $ \ x(t) \ = \ t^2 \ , \ y(t) \ = \ t^3 \ \ . \ $  The distance-squared function for a point on the curve to $ \ (-1 \ , \ 0) \ $ is then $ \ (x + 1)^2 + y^2 \ \rightarrow \ (t^2 + 1)^2 + t^6 \ \ , \ $ which is an even function with a single evident absolute minimum.

If the point instead should be $ \ (1 \ , \ 0) \ \ , \ $ the distance-squared function becomes $ \ (t^2 - 1)^2 + t^6 \ \ , \ $ which is again even and has a relative maximum at $ \ t \ = \ 0 \ $ and two (symmetric) absolute minima.  Both functions have derivatives which are a factor of $ \ t \ $ times a biquadratic function of $ \ t \ \ , \ $ making extremization reasonably simple.

**ADDENDUM (2/18)** --  For this point, the approach, mentioned in the comments, using normal lines to the curve also works:  at a point $ \ ( x \ , \ x^{3/2} ) \ $ on the curve, the line to $ \ (1 \ , \ 0 ) \ $ has slope $ \ \large{\frac{x^{3/2}}{x - 1} } \ $ which must equal the slope of the normal line $ \ \large{ -\frac{2}{3·x^{1/2}} } \ \ . \ $  Setting these equal produces a quadratic equation for which only one value of $ \ x \ $ is positive; symmetry of the curve about the $ \ x-$axis then gives the two points closest to $ \ (1 \ , \ 0) \ \ . \  $   This also shows why the Lagrange method was not helpful for $ \ ( -1 \ , \ 0) \ \ : \ $ because of the character of its concavity, the normal lines to the curve *cannot* pass through that point, indicated by the analogous quadratic equation $ \ 3x^2 + 2x + 2 \ = \ 0 \ $ having no real solutions.